# Suggestions for an academic project on Linux device driver programming

Tags: linux

I am doing training in LINUX OS and device driver programming (introduction). I need to work on a live project which can be completed within maximim 10 days days. This is part of my under graduation course requirement.

The project is compulsory and contributes to 70% of the total marks I get for this training. So a good project would contribute a lot in helping me score a good grade.

Any recommendations you might have taking into account the above topic? I had like my project to be learning experience - something in which I can apply what I have learned.

Any suggestions would be welcomed.

Comment: Do you have a specific question?

Comment: How about a basic joystick driver? Very few inputs but can expand in scope to cover lots of fancy stuff.

Comment: @Rushyo: Is it easy ? I only had a training of 6 weeks
@Robert: Its not compulsory to be device driver. It should be any live project related to Linux

Comment: Yes it has to be 10 days because i don't have much time to submit the project

Comment: @HSP That would depend on how narrow your training was and your ability to learn, I suppose.

Comment: @HSP But as devices go, a joystick is about as simple as it gets.

Comment: Ok so it means i can easily get a hold over programming for a joystick device driver. Can you suggest me where can i read about it ??

Comment: Writing device drivers isn't exactly basic stuff, I'm just suggesting joysticks are on the easier end of the scale. Resources for doing so would depend on your hardware.

Comment: I appreciate your help and very thankful that you came to my rescue but writing a device driver is very complex thing for an amateur like me. I don't have much knowledge in this field and moreover my training was not so good. So, can you please suggest me some other project ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about learning how to write a driver for a joystick, or game controller?

Below is a tutorial that shows how to write a Linux joystick driver in the node.js platform, the concepts and lessons learned can be easily applied to another platform.

[linux-joystick](http://nodebits.org/linux-joystick)

Hope this helps.